# Java return type after try/catch

Tags: java, android, return, try-catch

I want to return data of type String from my method i created. Eclipse says need to specifiy a return type after the try catch block... When I do that, Eclipse then tells me that I need to declare String data as a Local variable... What is going wrong here?

```
private String ReadData() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        String data = null;
        fis = KVOContact.this.openFileInput("data.txt");
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[fis.available()];
        isr.read(inputBuffer);
        data = new String(inputBuffer);
        isr.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("KVOContact", "IOError" + ioe);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're declaring `data` within the `try` block. It's out of scope outside that block.

You *could* just move the declaration to before the `try` block - but personally I think it would probably make more sense to remove the `catch` block entirely, and declare that the method can throw `IOException`. You should also close your `FileInputStream` and `InputStreamReader` in `finally` blocks so that you don't leave them open if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Ok... I don't understand what you mean by: Remove the catch block and declare that the method can throw IOException... Don't? you need to always catch the exception?

Comment: `private String ReadData() throws IOExeption{ }` remove the `try-catch` block and catch the exception in caller method.

Comment: @DennisvandenBrom: No, you don't need to catch the exception - you can declare that the method may throw it, and it will just bubble up. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The `data` variable is limited to the scope of the `try` clause. Declare it outside the `try` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in your code:

```
private String ReadData() {
    String data = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;        
        fis = KVOContact.this.openFileInput("data.txt");
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[fis.available()];
        isr.read(inputBuffer);
        data = new String(inputBuffer);
        isr.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("KVOContact", "IOError" + ioe);
    }
    return data;
}
```

You need to declare a String data variable not inside the try block, because otherwise it wont be seen outside the try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use `return` statement in catch part as well, study the following code,

```
private String ReadData() 
{
     try
     {
     .
     .
     . 
     return stringVariable;
     }
     catch ( IOException ioe )
     {
         Log.e("KVOContact", "IOError" + ioe);
         return NULL;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the return data statement inside the try block itself.

The catch will be called only when some error occurrs inside the try block otherwise the try gets executed and the call is returned to where it originated from.